# Drawing on top of literally everything

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, opengl

I want to create a utility program for gamers that runs in the background. What I need to do, is **display visible messages in-game** on certain occasions. So my window does not need to be visible at all time, but on some events (key combination, I have the tools to register global keys) it should pop up.

I started development in WPF, and if I set the Window property Topmost to true, it will remain on top, as long as I do not start another application, which wants to be the topmost. Of course games do want to be the topmost, so my window will not be visible. How should I approach this problem in WPF (if it is even possible to solve)?

If there is an easy solution in Winforms, I welcome that as well. Even a C++ OpenGL solution or tip would come in handy.

I know this is not a trivial task, but it is certainly possible to do. A good example of this is Xfire, where the user can chat meanwhile playing a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it's possible with using usual windows, but I have few suggestions & one solution.

1) Let the game start, and THEN set your Topmost property. Remember that theoretically the last window who set Topmost wins. Note that you might need to use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to remove/add Topmost to game/your window.

2) An actual solution involves hooking yourself into DirectX, assuming that most games run with DirectX. See [this](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/35950-directx9-base-hook/) thread for DIrect9X Base hook example. You can then custom draw game UI. You need to do a lot of work to support Direct9/10/11, and it can be dangerous too, since injecting to games is a security risk.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I will try out the first one, but I guess eventually the DirectX window will be preferred.

Comment: I tried out the first one, it did not work with full screen games. The second one I will have some trouble dealing with, since I have to import the DLL-s to c#, because the DX9 Hook API you referenced is written in C++.